# help identifying error: insert failed unable to lock row

Tags: apex, error

I have a process (apex controller) that creates a task when an order is placed.  This process has been running fine, but recently in the last month, we are starting to sporadically get the following error:

insert failed, unable to lock row: unable to obtain exclusive access to this record.

This seems to be a bit of a red herring because if I'm inserting a task, the record is just getting created so how can it be locked?

Is it possible that the task, which is related to a contact (whoId), which has a relationship to an account might be causing the lock due to a process running on one of those objects and therefore locks the task object?  I was reading about data skews and FOR UPDATE, but the later doesn't seem to apply and I can't figure out if a data skew on the lookup is the issue.  It doesn't happen every time, but it does happen right on the line that calls the method to create the task.

I'm at a loss of how to debug this and identify how to correct it?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Any triggers being called? For example, a trigger that rolls up some value to the related account, etcetera? It's possible that if you're not using FOR UPDATE you'll get this error more frequently than if you used row locks.

Comment: There is a task trigger from a managed package, but the code is obfuscated.  I have a batch process that does rollups from the task and event up to the contact, but that runs nightly and not during the day when this error occurs.  I've looked at queries that might cause this by not using FOR UPDATE, but I don't see any relevant query.  The error occurs when trying to insert tasks so would FOR UPDATE even apply?

Comment: It could, if the trigger tries to update a locked parent record. If the exception happens in managed code, you might need the developer's help with fixing it.

Comment: [related discussion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146454/possible-causes-of-unable-to-lock-row-error-during-insert-of-tasks) - basically, inserting a task puts locks on its parent whatId, whoId, accountId and any custom object lookups if Task status = Completed w/ activityDate - see [Locking Cheatsheet](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/record_locking_cheatsheet.pdf)